# Wiring new light fixture to 2-wire ceiling rose

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture, light

Any word of wisdom greatly appreciated. Wanted to install a new light in the living room and unexpectedly (for amateur as myself) i see 2 sets of wires in the ceiling rose i.e 2x L/N/E.

The room has 2 sets of lights, both will turn on/ off with a single switch, both on the same circuit. After some research and browsing through diagrams, i believe the wires i see suggest it’s end of the loop wiring?

New light fixture has got only place for one set of L|N|E and not sure how to go about this now.

Yes i know. It Would be decent if i’ve done a picture of how the wires looked like connected initially… realised that a bit too late.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to connect the two blue wires together with an additional piece of blue wire, the two brown together with an additional piece of brown wire and the same for the yellow/green. Use approved connectors, I don't think wire nuts are allowed. Then connect the single wire pieces to the light fixture. You should install a junction box there and not just screw the fixture into the wall.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Thanks. Just zoomed in and saw the green. I thought it was a yellow shrink tube.

Comment: It is yellow shrink tube, with a green stripe. That's on the list of legal ground colors even in North America. Also, the documentation with the new lamp, which was of course legitimate product acquired by a proper vendor and not straight-from-China, will say whether the terminals can support 2 wires.